# Angular2 Observable error handling in template

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-template

I like the approach of new angular with observables. It prevents us from writing a long chain of `.done().fail().always()`. like in JQuery. It is happening under the hood in NG2 using only `| async pipe`. But how about the case when there might be exceptional case while loading data for `myObservable`. Is there any way how to figure out that observable failed in template?

// sample.component.ts

```
class SimpleComponent{
   myObservable:Observable<string>;
   constructor(private _someService:SomeService){
       myObservable = _someService.getSomeDataByHttp();
   }
}
```

// simple.component.html

```
<div>
   <div>
      {{myObservable | async}}
   </div>
   <div (anyErrorInObservable)="myObservable"> // Some kind of construction to figure out that observable failed to load
       Oops, some kind of error appeared while fetching myObservable.
   </div>
</div>
```

I know that this can be done using `.catch()`. But I hope that there is some kind of better approach.

Thanks for any advance

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to handle errors in the template. You can use operators like `catch()` to ensure errors don't reach the template.

See also this related open issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7539